# is there a way to check if s3 object exist and not same size?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, auto-update

I googled that there is `doesObjectExist` to check if object exists but possible to check the size too?

What I want is, is the size is different then `putObject` to update it if the size is the same then do nothing because there's no point uploading again if there's no changes.

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Yes you can. What language and which SDK are you using? You should also create a custom header with the LastUpdateTime and store that in the S3 object metadata. Then check both the LastUpdateTime and object size to determine file changes.

Comment: @JohnHanley using nodejs

Comment: @JohnHanley by custom header you meant meta data?

Comment: Yes, when you create or overwrite an S3 object, you can include a custom HTTP header such as `x-amz-meta-mycompany-modifiedtime` and store a timestamp that matches the original source file. This is stored in S3 as metadata just like `content-type`. It is possible to modify a file without changing the size and by checking data and object length you will have an accurate method.

Comment: There is even a better solution than size + last update time: Each object in S3 hash its hash stored with it you can check if the objects are really identical.

Comment: @Dunedan can you tell me more about it or provide example? PS, I am doing this locally so not storing anything on db

Comment: @JohnHanley thx, I kinda get the idea of it.  Let me test it out

Comment: I think what you really might want is to try to upload and only upload if the objects differ. The following answer details how that works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1775831/4779904

Comment: @Dunedan - Using the etag header for md5 is not reliable today. That answer is outdated.

Comment: @JohnHanley I was trying to compare the `modified time` and `size` that I saved into the `meta`  but I modified date + size wouldn't be too accurate. Even I tried pulling binary from s3 and compare with binary local without editing or saving, the binary is still different.  Is there a better accurate way to compare?

Comment: What date are you checking? Your own custom date header, which can be accurate to milliseconds or the Cloud Storage header? Create a new question, show your code and ping me with the new question link.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have just posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53952559/accurate-method-to-compare-the-s3-object-and-local-object